# Question about functionals on $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a compact topological space with a regular Borel measure $\mu$. In particular $\mu$ is a finite measure. Assume $f\in L^1(X)$.Suppose $1\leq p<\infty$ and $D\subset L^p(X)$ is a dense subset. Assume that the map $$T_f:D\rightarrow \mathbb C$$$$h\mapsto \int_Xhfd\mu $$ is a bounded linear functional. Then is $f$ necessarily in $L^{p'}$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$?

I know that $T_f$ extends uniquely to a bounded linear functional $$T_f:L^p(X)\rightarrow \mathbb C$$ So $\exists! \ g\in L^{p'}(X)$ such that $T_f(h)=\displaystyle\int_Xhgd\mu=T_g(h) $

Since $C(X)\hookrightarrow L^p(X)$ is continuous, we get $T_f,T_g\in C(X)^*=\mathcal M(X)$, the space of regular complex Borel measures. The corresponding complex measures are

$$\mu_f(K)=\displaystyle\int_K fd\mu $$

$$\mu_g(K)=\displaystyle\int_K gd\mu $$

But $T_f, T_g$ agree on $C(X)$ and hence $\mu_g=\mu_f$ i.e. for all $K\subset X$, compact $$\int_K fd\mu=\int_K g d\mu $$$$\implies f=g \ \text{a.e.}$$
In particular $f\in L^{p'}(X)$.

I hope this is an okay solution. I would be glad if someone can give an alterbative solution without using complex measures.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your notation: is $f \in L^1$? Usually, we don't have $L^1 \simeq (L^\infty)^*$

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. All I am using is $(L^p)^*=L^{p'}$  for $1\leq p <\infty$. This is certainly true for all $\sigma$-finite measure spaces as in this case.

Comment: Ok, but in your second line you assume $f \in L^1$. Seems that we are considering $p' = 1$ and $T_f \in (L^\infty)^*$. Is it a typo or something? I am not sure if we need to define $f \in L^1$. But if we only assume $T_f$ defines a bounded linear functional on $D \subset L^p$, then the unique extension to $\tilde{T_f}: L^p \to \mathbb{C}$ already says $f \in L^{p'}$. All you need to show is that $\tilde{T_f}(h)$ is also in the form of $\int h f$.

Comment: For your proof, I think most of it is correct, and indeed what needs to be shown is 1) that $T_f \in C(X)^*$ (here, you need to show $T_f$ is bounded "after extension") and 2) that  after extension, the corresponding measure takes the form of $\mu_f(K) = \int_K f d\mu$. Why the integrand should be $f$?

Comment: I am actually not extending $T_f$ to $C(X)$. Since $C(X)\hookrightarrow L^p$, I am looking at the restriction. In this restriction, $T_f(h)=\int_X hf d\mu$ since the integral exists.

Comment: Yes, I understand, you are extending to $L^p$ and so the restriction is clearly a continuous functional. The restriction $T_f: C(X) \to \mathbb{C}$ is in the form $T_f(h) = \int_X hf d\mu$ actually needs some efforts; in fact, even the extension to $T_f: L^p \to \mathbb{C}$ is in that form (do this by extracting sequence). But if you show the extension in that form, then by the unique correspondence between $(L^p)^*$ and $L^{p'}$ says $f \in L^{p'}$. Overall your proof looks good to me. I am just saying something additional.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can start just assuming $f$ is a measurable function, but you need $D$ to be a dense **subspace** of $L^p(X)$, closed by restriction to measurable subsets of $X$.
In particular, if $h \in D$, then $h \;\sigma(h) \;\sigma(f) \in D$, where, if $g$ is measurable function, $\sigma(g)$ is  the sign function of $g$.

The detailed proof is presented below  and it does not use complex measure as $C(X)^*$.

> Suppose $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a compact topological space with a regular Borel measure $\mu$. In particular $\mu$ is a finite measure. Assume $f$ is a measurable function. Suppose $1\leq p<\infty$ and $D\subset L^p(X)$ is a dense subspace. Assume that the map
> \begin{align*}
> T_f:& D\rightarrow \mathbb C\\ &h\mapsto \int_Xhfd\mu 
> \end{align*}
> is a bounded linear functional (and for the case $p=1$ assume $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite).
> Then $f \in L^{p'}$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$.

**Proof**:

Given any $h\in L^p(X)$, since $D$ is dense, there is a sequence $\{h_m\}_m$ such that, for all $m$ , $h_m \in D$  and $h_m \rightarrow h$ in $L^p(X)$. Taking a subsequence if needed, we can assume that that $h_m \rightarrow h$ a.e.. So, we have that $h_m f \rightarrow h f$ a.e.

Now, since
\begin{align*}
T_f:& D\rightarrow \mathbb C\\ &h\mapsto \int_Xhfd\mu 
\end{align*}
is a bounded linear functional and $D$ is a subspace closed by restriction to measurable subsets of $X$, we have, for every $n$, $m$, $(h_n - h_m)\sigma(h_n - h_m) \sigma(f) \in D$ and
\begin{align*}
\int |h_n f - h_m f|  d\mu & = \left |  \int |h_n  - h_m | |f|  d\mu     \right| \\
& =  \left | \int [(h_n - h_m)\sigma(h_n - h_m) \sigma(f)] f d\mu  \right|  \\
& \leqslant K \| (h_n - h_m)\sigma(h_n - h_m) \sigma(f) \|_p = K \| h_n - h_m \|_p
\end{align*}

So the sequence $\{h_mf\}_m$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(X)$. So there is $k\in L^1(X)$ such that $ h_mf \rightarrow k $ in $L^1(X)$. Taking a subsequence we have $h_{m_i}f \rightarrow k$ a.e.. But we already know that  $h_m f \rightarrow h f$ a.e.. So we can conclude that $k=hf$ a.e., $ h_mf \rightarrow hf $ in $L^1(X)$ and
$$
T_f(h_m) =\int h_mf d\mu \rightarrow \int hf d\mu
$$

We know that $T_f$ extends uniquely to a bounded linear functional $\overline{T}_f$ defined on $L^p(X)$. From what we just proved above, we have
\begin{align*}
\overline{T}_f:& L^p(X)\rightarrow \mathbb C\\ &h\mapsto \int_Xhfd\mu \end{align*}
So $\exists! \ g\in L^{p'}(X)$ such that $\overline{T}_f(h)=\displaystyle\int_Xhgd\mu=T_g(h) $.

So, we have, for all $h \in L^p(X)$,
$$ \int_Xhfd\mu = \int_Xhgd\mu <\infty$$
So , for all $h \in L^p(X)$,
$ \displaystyle\int_Xh(f-g)d\mu = 0$.
So $f=g$ a.e..

**Remark:** Let us prove the last step in detail.
Suppose there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\mu([f-g > \varepsilon]) >0 $. Since $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure, there is $K$ compact such that $K\subseteq  [f-g > \varepsilon]$ and $0<\mu(K)<\infty$. So $\chi_K \in L^p(X)$ and
$$ 0= \int_X \chi_K (f-g)d\mu > \varepsilon \mu(K) >0 $$
Contradiction. So, for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\mu([f-g > \varepsilon]) = 0 $. So $f\leqslant g$ a.e.. In a similar way, considering $\mu([f-g <- \varepsilon]) >0 $, we prove that $g \leqslant h$ a.e.. So $f=g$ a.e..

**Remark:** Proving the exact form of the extension of $T_f$ is the tricky part of this problem.

Comment: I have a slight problem with this. Why is $\int_X hfd\mu $ defined for all $h\in L^p$? What I mean is, surely it extends to a bounded linear functional but why should it be given by precisely this integration.

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician You could see this by extracting a sequence $h_n \in D \to h$, and using the boundedness of $T_f$.

Comment: Don't we need to invoke Banach-Steinhaus/uniform boundedness at some point?

Comment: @IgnorantMathematician You are right. It is tricky to prove that the extension is given precisely by that integration. Thanks for pointing it.  I edited the answer to include the details.

Comment: @mathdoge You are right. The exact form of the extension can be proved by extracting sequences and using the boundedness of $T_f$. It is tricky and I edit my answer to include the details.

Comment: @paulgarrett Not directly for this solution. However, there are other solutions  that would use Banach-Steinhaus. I am aware of at least one of them.

Comment: thanks a lot @Ramiro . In my problem, I could show elements of $D$ were continuous so I could get away without the technical details you included. Thanks a lot for this nice solution!